# Page link after clicking image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to simply have the page relocate depending on what image is pressed on a webpage. I had the code right before, but to 100 things i had to do to fix stuff, its not working anymore. Can anyone figure out why?

So when you click on the image `cloudybubble.png` thats on the page now, it will bring you to `cloudy_name.php`. And there would be other images that bring you to other pages to do that as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>WhethertheWeather</title>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/css/screen.css" media="all" />-->
        <script src="http://www.adrianpelletier.com/mint/?js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/scripts/execute.js"></script>


<script>
    function showWeather(_Weather) {
     //alert(Weather);
        myform._Weather.value=Weather;
    //  alert(Weather);

    // ._Weather
        myform.submit();



        }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('cloudybubble.png').click(function() {
            window.location="http://http://www.tcnjart.com/christineaustin/whethertheweather/cloudy_name.php;"
        });
    });

    // window.location="http://http://www.tcnjart.com/christineaustin/whethertheweather/cloudy_name.php"; //
</script>


</script>


<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body background="images/gradientsky.jpg"> 



<div id="weather">

<ul id="nav-reflection">
<form method="post" action="cloudy_name.php" id="myform">
        <li class="button-color-1"><a href="javascript:showWeather('cloudy')"; title="My fancy link"><img src="images/cloudybubble.png" width="211" height="180" align="left"></a></li>

    <input type="hidden" name="weather" value="whatever">
</form>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

New script

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>WhethertheWeather</title>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/css/screen.css" media="all" />-->
        <script src="http://www.adrianpelletier.com/mint/?js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/scripts/execute.js"></script>


<script>
    function showWeather(_Weather) {
     //alert(Weather);
        myform._Weather.value=Weather;
    //  alert(Weather);

    // ._Weather
        myform.submit();



        }

    $('#cloudybubble').click(function() {
    window.location = "http://http://www.tcnjart.com/christineaustin/whethertheweather/cloudy_name.php;"
});

</script>


</script>


<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body background="images/gradientsky.jpg"> 



<div id="weather">

<ul id="nav-reflection">
<form method="post" action="cloudy_name.php" id="myform">
        <li class="button-color-1"><a href="javascript:showWeather('cloudy')"; title="My fancy link"><img id="cloudybubble" src="images/cloudybubble.png" width="211" height="180" align="left" />
</a></li>

    <input type="hidden" name="weather" value="whatever">
</form>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the JavaScript console say?

Comment: idk, I'm not actually sure what code to use to debug it..I'm kinda new to javascript

Comment: In Firefox you can find the console under Tools->Error Console. I'm not sure about other browsers. It's definitely the first place you should look when something goes wrong.

Comment: Your URL is also invalid - note the double `http://` in the link.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you aren't able to just let the hyperlink work as normal?

Comment: Tieson T. is right about the double http://. The semicolon at the end should also be moved outside of the quotes.

Comment: Ah yes, stupid me, but that hasn't fixed it.  :[ and @TiesonT. in in the current `href` I have `"javascript:showWeather('cloudy')";` which I need because I'm trying to have a weather variable saved in a database depending on which icon is clicked. (you click the cloudy bubble, 'cloudy' gets saved in my database). Thats why I'm not just putting it in there

Comment: What you're trying to do is submit a form, then redirect the page. That will not work. As soon as you submit the form it will navigate to cloudy_name.php. The JavaScript will not execute further and it will not navigate to another address specified. At this point I've addressed your original question to the best of my ability. Discussing your requirements further via comments is not a good idea. I suggest asking a different question on how to solve your logging problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely do that on the server side.

What if your user doesn't have javascript? Trust me, there are a lot of them (mostly for security reasons).

Define the action of your form to some PHP page, process the changes or w/e you need to do, and redirect the user accordingly (with `header('Location: http://www.hi.com');`).

Comment: They should give feedback. I did not downvote, but I have my own response. We don't have enough information at hand to determine if a client vs server side approach would be ideal. Sometimes the choice is limited based on the client's requirements. I've implemented this both ways. Given what was asked, I would say a client-side approach is acceptable. I also wrote mine so that if JavaScript is disabled, the link will still navigate.

Comment: At this point I have to agree it would be most viable to implement the requirements server-side. The question asked how to solve something, I addressed that, but ultimately, the entire approach was flawed. It can still be done with the redirection done client-side, but if they're posting to a PHP file, well, it's easiest to handle it all there.

Comment: I unfotunatly have little to no idea how to process something like that server sided. If you two are still interesting in helping me out, I created a new question like @WillKlein stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273222/saving-a-variable-through-clicking-an-image)

Comment: Just some advice... people on Stack Overflow love helping others. It gets tough if there is more than one problem involved. Try to break up your questions as much as possible. That should reap the greatest benefit for everyone involved.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: revised to account for new information in comments.

We can make this work genericly for ALL images an your page so they use the same JavaScript.

In the HTML, put the hyperlink back in the a tag. Then, add a class to the a tag, I suggest "weatherLink". Then put the text you want to log in the database, i.e. "cloudy", and make that the id for the link.

HTML:

```
<li class="button-color-1">
    <a id="cloudy" class="weatherLink" href="http://www.tcnjart.com/christineaustin/whethertheweather/cloudy_name.php" title="My fancy link">
        <img src="images/cloudybubble.png" width="211" height="180" align="left" />
    </a>
</li>
```

Now our JavaScript needs the jQuery click handler updated as follows.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.weatherLink').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showWeather(this.id);
        window.location.href = this.href;
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now, if you add any other images, just leave the hyperlink in the a tag, give it the weatherLink class, and give it a unique id that can be passed to showWeather(). Given the right HTML, you do NOT need to duplicate any more JavaScript.

Here is a jsFiddle test page for you to see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/willslab/jkB9z/9/

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to be working still. All I did was delete the script I had before and imputed the one you added here.

Comment: and for the id, would i just do `img id="images/cloudybubble.png" width="211" height="180" align="left"></a></li>`

Comment: Not like that... see the HTML snippet I added. You need to keep the src tag, and the id should not have special characters. Just add id="cloudybubble".

Comment: Hmm, still not working, not sure why...I updated my code above. Maybe the script is getting confused?

Comment: I think I know what it is. In the a tag that wraps the img, update the href to look like href="#" with no semicolon outside the quotes. That was giving me a JavaScript error.

Comment: I added an HTML snippet to illustrate the change.

Comment: You need to fix the broken link, as Tieson T. pointed out. There is an extra http:// and the semicolon at the end needs to be moved outside of the quotes.

Comment: Ok, I've revised my answer to account for the several things we found. Let me know if you have any questions. ^_^

Comment: Still curious why we need JavaScript here. @ChristineAustin, would it not be easier to just use a normal `<a>` tag? `window.location` performs the same thing as just clicking on a normal link

Comment: Ah... this is very true! At least based on what we see here. Tieson T., post that as an answer and I'll upvote. I couldn't agree more.

Comment: in in the current `href` I have `<a "javascript:showWeather('cloudy')";`which I need because I'm trying to have a weather variable saved in a database depending on which icon is clicked. (you click the cloudy bubble, 'cloudy' gets saved in my database). Thats why I'm not just putting it in there

Comment: Oh, if THAT's the case, I have a MUCH better solution. I'll update my solution now.

Comment: Through this method, would the `cloudy` variable know to be stored under the proper column of a table? (in this case the table name is `stories`, and the column it is stored in is `weather`)

Comment: I cannot tell that from the client side code if that is what's happening. I can only tell you that your showWeather function will be called the way it was intended. It is then up to your server-side code to handle the posted values. You may need more changes to be done in showWeather() but that is far beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: And i dont understand whats going on, the image still isnt linking even though it looks fine in the fsfiddle link. [You can see it here](http://www.tcnjart.com/christineaustin/whethertheweather/test.html)

Comment: Woah, cool page! The problem is now in the showWeather() function... that has it's own problems. It works in my jsFiddle because I commented that out. I thought it was a work in progress with the commented lines and all.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` to your `img` tag and use it in your selector.