# Saving a variable through clicking an image

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I've been struggling with this for sometime now and still cant seem to find and answer. On my webpage I have 6 different individual pictures of weather. When the user clicks one, I want it to do two things-

1) Save a variable to a table (Ex- You press the cloudy picture, 'cloudy' is saved to my table under the 'weather' colomn)

2) It will redirect you to the next page (in this page you will enter a name, then submit that to the table and it will redirect you to another page where you will submit a story relating to the weather)

As a result, this information will all be posted on a form that people can see. But my main issue is i cant get the weather variable to save to the database table AND redirect you to the next page, anyone know of a way?

Here are two codes code I had some help on trying to figure out.

http://jsfiddle.net/np5Mv/

and

http://jsfiddle.net/wDwSC/

Comment: pls use jsfiddle for long chunks of code, and be so kind to remove all unnecessary debug code beforehand, btw the current jquery version is 1.7.2 you are using 1.3.2

Comment: too much bs at once, not going to answer this

Comment: I'm sorry @mightyuhu , I put everything into jsfiddle like you asked. Sorry for the stupidity on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an

```
<input type="image" src="cloudy.png" alt="Cloudy" name="weather" value="cloudy">
```

then the image will act (mostly) the same as a form submit button would with the same name/value. No javascript needed at all.

Comment: What if i have a hovering float effect going on? Like, when the user scrolls over the image, it floats up several pixels. How would I input that? (controlled by `<li class="button-color-1">`)